# regular expression for all characters not in this range AND another character

Tags: regex

I need to strip all characters that are not part of the ASCII standard EXCEPT FROM one other character.

In order to find all the non-ASCII character I use this regex:

```
/[^\x01-\x7F]/
```

In order to exclude the character \x92 as well, how must I rewrite the regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just stick it in there with the others:

```
/[^\x01-\x7F\x92]/
```

The elements of a character class can be individual characters or character ranges, and they can be freely mixed just by sticking them one after the other.